# Implementing a Custom Vertical Scroll Bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use a custom vertical scroll bar, something sleek to go with my web page design. 
I found this tutorial online: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?L_dwB4rN and it's just not working out for me and im not sure why... I downloaded all of the files that it specifies, put them in the right folder etc. and it's not working.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <!--<script src="jquery.scrollbars.js"></script>-->
        <link href="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script>
            (function($){
                $(window).load(function(){
                    $("#aboutinfo").mCustomScrollbar({
                        verticalScroll:true,
                        theme:"light"
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
     <div id="container">   
        <div id="nav">
            <p id="np">NAME PLACEHOLDER</p>
            <p id="about"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></p>
            <p id="srv"><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></p>
            <p id="pjt"><a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a></p>
            <p id="cont"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></p>
        </div>

        <div id="aboutinfo">
            <p>
                A variation of the common lorem ipsum text has been used since the 1960s or earlier[1] to provide a filler text during typesetting.
The text is derived from sections 1.10.32–3 of Cicero's De finibus bonorum et malorum (On the Ends of Goods and Evils, or alternatively [About] The Purposes of Good and Evil).[2] The original passage began: Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci velit (translation: "Neither is there anyone who loves, pursues or desires pain itself because it is pain"). It is not known exactly when the text acquired its current standard form; it may have been as late as the 1960s. Richard McClintock, a Latin scholar who was the publications director at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, discovered the source of the passage sometime before 1982 while searching for instances of the Latin word "consectetur", rarely used in classical literature.[1][3] The physical source of the Lorem Ipsum text may be the 1914 Loeb Classical Library Edition of the De Finibus, where the Latin text finishes page 34 with "Neque porro quisquam est qui do-" and begins page 36 with "lorem ipsum (et seq.)…", suggesting that the galley type of that page was scrambled to make the dummy text seen today. This suggests that "lorem ipsum" may have been used as dummy text before the Letraset transfer sheets popularized it.

            </p>        
        </div>


      </div>


      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*NAVIGATION*/
a{
  color:black;
  text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover,a:active
{
 color:#C8C8C8;
}

#np{
    position:relative;
    right:100px;
    font-size:20px;
}


/*PAGE SET UP */

body{
    background-color:#F8F8F8;
}

#container{
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    z-index:15;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;


}


/*CONTACT STYLE*/
#cntinfo{
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
    top:40px;
    width:400px;
}


/*ABOUT STYLE*/
#aboutinfo{
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
    top:40px;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:auto;

}
```

Comment: have you checked script console for any errors? Ctrl+Shift+J on chrome.

Comment: @ariel thanks for the tip, did not know that! And yes there is an error so i'll try to fix that.